# Find index of a key? Dictionary .NET

Tags: .net, linq

I need to do currentKey+1. So i would like to find the index of the key value and get the next key (or first if at end). How do i find the current index of the key?

I am using a `Dictionary<int, classname>` and i looked for .Find or IndexOf with Linq to no avail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dictionaries are not sorted, so the Key doesn't have any index really. See my question here: [Accessing a Dictionary.Keys Key through a numeric index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227/)

Use an [OrderedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx) which has an [indexer that takes an Int](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132598.aspx).

**Edit:** 'm not really sure I understand what you want. If you want to iterate through a Dictionary, just use

```
foreach(KeyValuePair kvp in yourDict)
```

If the key is an Int and you want the next, use

```
var newkey = oldkey+1;
if(yourdict.ContainsKey(newkey)){
    var newvalue = yourdict[newkey];
}
```

If the ints are not sequential, you can use

```
var upperBound = d.Max(kvp => kvp.Key)+1; // to prevent infinite loops
while(!yourdict.ContainsKey(newkey) && newkey < upperBound) {
    newkey++;
}
```

or, alternatively:

```
var keys = (from key in yourdict.Keys orderby key select key).ToList();
// keys is now a list of all keys in ascending order
```

Comment: Or an OrderedDictionary: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary_members.aspx

Comment: @mwilson Very true, I've changed my answer. `Queue<Tuple<TKey,TValue>>` sounded really stupid anyway :)

Comment: hmm, in my function each time i call it should i copy the keys into a list, sort it then use prev/next with that? (i'd still find the current index by scanning the value)

Comment: I dont need order they been added, i need order of key value

Comment: Accepted for the `var keys = (from key in yourdict.Keys orderby key select key).ToList();` answer. My favourable solution. I got it wrong when i tried to write it without reading yours (carefully). I wrote orderby yourdict.Keys[keys] by mistake. Yikes (and ouch, threw an exception which is good but i was confused)

Comment: oh man. I have no idea what i did or why i am doing this. To bad i didnt write any hints about what i was working on

Answer (score 2):

As Michael Stum noted, `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is not sorted (it's a hashtable) so there is no such thing as the "index" of a key. Instead, you can use [SortedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist.aspx) which *is* (as the name implies) sorted and does provide an [IndexOfKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist.indexofkey.aspx) method.

Be aware that the performance characteristics of `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is different to `SortedList<TKey, TValue>` though. While Dictionary is O(1) for inserts and deletes, SortedList is O(logn).

Answer (score 2):

Without using a different collection it could be done like this. Though I'm not sure how efficient this is.

```
classIndex = classes.ToList().IndexOf(new KeyValuePair<int, classname>(newKey, classes[newKey]));
```

Comment: Or classIndex = classes.Keys.ToList().IndexOf(newKey)