# How to enumerate through Dictionary

Tags: c#

How can I retreive elemenents in Dictionary through index (int index )..;Instead of a key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dictionary is an unordered collection so it does not provide random access.  Only types that implement [`IList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6.aspx) provide random access to their contents.

Well, that's not totally correct - you could use a [`OrderedDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx) (which would give you random access without `IList<T>`) but you lose the benefits of the generic dictionary.  If you need random access, most likely you shouldn't be using a Dictionary.

Answer (score 6):

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<String,String> pair in dictionary)
{
     string key = pair.Key;
     string value = pair.Value;
}
```

or to get access by item

```
dictionary.ToList()[index].Key/Value    :-)
```

Answer (score 3):

check out following

[Accessing a Dictionary.Keys Key through a numeric index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227/c-accessing-a-dictionary-keys-key-through-a-numeric-index)

Comment: That should be a comment on the question.

Answer (score 2):

There is no method for retrieving elements by index because the Dictionary class does not specify the order in which key/value pairs are stored.  If you need both key and index lookup use the [OrderedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx) class.

Answer (score 1):

I found this useful:

```
foreach (var key in dictionary.Keys)
{
    var value = dictionary[key];
}
```

or

```
foreach (var value in dictionary.Values)
{
    // use value
}
```